# Disable Automatic Capitalization Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

How do I disable Automatic Capitalization in Windows Phone 7 with the keyboard when my user doesn't want there words auto capitalized in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is determined by the `InputScope` of the TextBox.

You can change this to something which doesn't have the behaviour you don't want by setting it to something which behaves as desired.

See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg521152(v=vs.92).aspx
and
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426929(VS.95).aspx